# I want to make a BioMetric Attendence System in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't Have any Idea about FingerPrint Scanner. Anyone know about how to save fingerPrint into database and match the fingerPrints in C# Asp.net. I'm using DigitalPersona and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. 
Do you give me some code snippets for this?
I shall be very thankful to you...

Regards
Zargham Nazeer Malik

Comment: This is a really complex topic involving fields as diverse as biometrics, machine learning and statistics. You might want to read up on some of those.

Comment: sir I'm new to use FIngerPrint Scanner. So, I want to learn it from starting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using digital persona. after installing , a folder will be saved in c directory. Please check , code is present in that folder.It could already register and verify fingerprints

Below code is to save in database....

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
fingerprintData.Position = 0;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);

//Insert the file into database
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.115.5.3; Initial Catalog=EnrollmentSampledb;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblUser VALUES(@ID_NUMBER, @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME, @FINGERPRINT, @DATE_ADDED, @DATE_MODIFIED)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("ID_NUMBER", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tboxIdNum.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tboxFname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("LASTNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tboxLname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("FINGERPRINT", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes;
cmd.Parameters.Add("DATE_ADDED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("DATE_MODIFIED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();

tboxIdNum.Text = "";
tboxFname.Text = "";
tboxLname.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks But its datatype is image or something else?? using sqlserver 2008

Comment: please go through http://www.digitalpersona.com/uploadedFiles/Support/Reference_Material/Guides/SDK_Guides/Pro-SDK-.NET-Developer-Guide.pdf[^]

Comment: The code is giving error on Template.Serialize
I can't undrstand

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Red Line Under Template.Serialize 
Any Library for Template.serialize??

Comment: try right click resolve, if verification is going correct then only u will get that template, is rest other code is correct ?